# Is Yolov7 model with higher precision better than another version of it that has higher mAP@0.5?

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, yolo, yolov7

I have trained two versions of Yolov7 models for road object detection. One is the main version of Yolov7 and the other one is the modified version of the main version of Yolov7. The main model has given a higher mAP@0.5 but with lower precision on the test dataset. However, the modified version has given Higher Precision but with lower mAP@0.5 on the test dataset. Is the modified model better than the main model in any perspective?

This is the result of the main Yolov7 model:

[image]

This is the result of the modified Yolov7 model:

[image]

Please, kindly analyze the results and tell me if the modified model is better than the main model from any point of view because of having the higher precision?

Comment: Looking at the `all` category only, one metric went up, one went down, both changed by less than 1%. It really sounds to me like nothing really changed in your modified version.

Comment: But the precision and recall metrics have higher differences. Do these metrics make any of these models better from any point of view?

Comment: There are ways to combine precision and recall into a single score, such as the [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-score). The [Intersection over Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) is similar but less applicable to multi-class classification